# connect youtube through curl?

Tags: php, curl, youtube-api

i have connected youtube through curl to upload videos from my sever , following is my code

```
<?php
$youtube_email = "------------------------"; // Change this to your youtube sign in email.
$youtube_password = "----------------"; // Change this to your youtube sign in password.

$postdata = "Email=".$youtube_email."&Passwd=".$youtube_password."&service=youtube&source=Example";
$curl = curl_init("https://www.google.com/youtube/accounts/ClientLogin");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
$rr= curl_getinfo($curl);

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
 print_r($response);
?
```

it is perfectly working in my localhost , but in my sever i got following error,

```
Error=BadAuthentication Url=https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?service=youtube#Email=xxxx@gmail.com
```

what is the problem here?

Comment: What are the Curl and PHP versions on both your localhost and your server? http://php.net/curl_version

Comment: have you approved your application to access the youtube api for your remote server and your username/password?