# Upload the files from live server to youtube is not working?

Tags: php, xml, curl, youtube, youtube-api

I am working in you tube API integration.This code works perfectly in local host.But its not working live server.further its not upload video from live server to YouTube.I am not able to upload video on youtube from my live server.I am trying to solve nearly 2days..This is sample code for upload video to YouTube.

```
 <?php
    $youtube_email = "xxxxxxxx"; // Change this to your youtube sign in email.
    $youtube_password = "xxxxxxxxx"; // Change this to your youtube sign in password.

    $postdata = "Email=".$youtube_email."&Passwd=".$youtube_password."&service=youtube&source=Example";
    $curl = curl_init("https://www.google.com/youtube/accounts/ClientLogin");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    list($auth, $youtubeuser) = explode("\n", $response);
    list($authlabel, $authvalue) = array_map("trim", explode("=", $auth));
    list($youtubeuserlabel, $youtubeuservalue) = array_map("trim", explode("=", $youtubeuser));

    $youtube_video_title = "kamal"; // This is the uploading video title.
    $youtube_video_description = "kamal"; // This is the uploading video description.
    $youtube_video_category = "News"; // This is the uploading video category.
    $youtube_video_keywords = "kamal, video"; // This is the uploading video keywords.

    $data = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
                <entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
                  xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"
                  xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
                  <media:group>
                    <media:title type="plain">'.$youtube_video_title.'</media:title>
                    <media:description type="plain">'.$youtube_video_description.'</media:description>
                    <media:category
                      scheme="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat">'.$youtube_video_category.'</media:category>
                    <media:keywords>'.$youtube_video_keywords.'</media:keywords>
                  </media:group>
                </entry>';

    $key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; // Get your key here: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard/.

    $headers = array("Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=".$authvalue,
                     "GData-Version: 2",
                     "X-GData-Key: key=".$key,
                     "Content-length: ".strlen($data),
                     "Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8");

    $curl = curl_init("http://gdata.youtube.com/action/GetUploadToken");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    $response = simplexml_load_string(curl_exec($curl));
    curl_close($curl);
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function checkForFile() {
        if (document.getElementById('file').value) {
          return true;
        }
        document.getElementById('errMsg').style.display = '';
        return false;
      }
    </script>

    <?php
    $nexturl = "http%3A%2F%2Fwww.walola.com"; // This parameter specifies the URL to which YouTube will redirect the user's browser when the user uploads his video file.
    ?>

    <form action="<?php echo($response->url); ?>?nexturl=<?php echo(urlencode($nexturl)); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkForFile();">
      <input id="file" type="file" name="file"/>
      <div id="errMsg" style="display:none;color:red">
        You need to specify a file.
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo($response->token); ?>"/>
      <input type="submit" value="go" />

    </form>
    </php>
```

Please provide approximate solutions for this....ASAP...

Comment: Is there any difference between local server conf and live one? What append exactly when you try to upload a video?

Comment: What are the Curl and PHP versions on both your localhost and your server? Are you getting the same error message as in [connect youtube through curl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15270967/367456) - btw which error message do you get?

Comment: HI hakre.. on local host machine video upload success generate you tube code on browser url, but live server return page not found errors

Answer (score 1):

The page that's loaded after the browser-based upload completes is determined by the URL you pass in as the `nexturl=` parameter in the `action` attribute of the form, as explained in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_browser_based_uploading#Uploading_the_Video_File).

You're passing `<?php echo(urlencode($nexturl)); ?>` as the value there, so if you're getting a page not found response when the upload's complete, it's because of that value.

Looking at your code, I think the problem is that your `$nexturl` value is "http%3A%2F%2Fwww.walola.com", which is already URL escaped, and then you're calling `urlencode()` on it. Try using "http://www.walola.com" for `$nexturl` instead and then calling `urlencode()` on that.